# Converting tutorial to a running program in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am trying to convert the tutorial here http://atnos-org.github.io/eff/org.atnos.site.Introduction.html into a running *Scala* program inside *IntelliJ-IDEA*.  The code runs in the command line REPL, but not in the IDE.

I have simply copied and pasted all the code into one file, added an `object Intro extends App`

Here is the code:

```
class Tutorial{

}

object Intro extends App {
  import cats._
  import cats.data._
  import org.atnos.eff._

  type ReaderInt[A] = Reader[Int, A]
  type WriterString[A] = Writer[String, A]

  type Stack = Fx.fx3[WriterString, ReaderInt, Eval]

  import org.atnos.eff.all._
  import org.atnos.eff.syntax.all._

  // useful type aliases showing that the ReaderInt and the WriterString effects are "members" of R
  // note that R could have more effects
  type _readerInt[R]    = ReaderInt |= R
  type _writerString[R] = WriterString |= R


  def program[R: _readerInt : _writerString : _eval]: Eff[R, Int] = for {
  // get the configuration
    n <- ask[R, Int]

    // log the current configuration value
    _ <- tell("the required power is " + n)

    // compute the nth power of 2
    a <- delay(math.pow(2, n.toDouble).toInt)

    // log the result
    _ <- tell("the result is " + a)
  } yield a


  println(program[Stack].runReader(6).runWriter.runEval.run)
}
```

The compiler error is `Cannot resolve symbol run` in the last line.

Here is my build.sbt file, following the instructions for the library:

```
name := "Tutorial"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats" % "0.9.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.atnos" %% "eff" % "3.1.0"

// to write types like Reader[String, ?]
addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" %% "kind-projector" % "0.9.3")

// to get types like Reader[String, ?] (with more than one type parameter) correctly inferred
// this plugin is not necessary with Scala 2.12
addCompilerPlugin("com.milessabin" % "si2712fix-plugin_2.11.8" % "1.2.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Edmund Noble answered my question here: https://github.com/atnos-org/eff/issues/80#issuecomment-287667353

> The reason why IntelliJ cannot figure out your code in particular looks to be because IntelliJ is not capable of simulating implicit-directed type inference; the Member implicits have a type member, Out, inside them which represents the remaining effect stack. If the IDE cannot figure it out, it subs in a fresh type variable and thus the run ops constructor cannot be called because the inferred type according to IntelliJ is `Eff[m.Out, A]` and not `Eff[NoFx, A]`.

**FIX**: I was able to separately compile the file and then run it, even though the error is still highlighted in the IDE.

Unless there is some feature in IntelliJ IDEA that I haven't enabled, this looks like a limitation and/or bug in IntelliJ IDEA .